# How can I debug this memory usage / dom usage increase in my JS/Update panel site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, updatepanel

I'm hoping some Javascript/ASP.Net gurus can give me some hints here.

I've written an application which (unfortunately) uses UpdatePanel (yes, I'm aware that was a dumb idea, too late now though, I understand it more now - even though its an intranet site I'm having troubles with it)

The site is a web based timesheet site, kind of tabular format. Anyhow, it basically saves everything in it in an update panel, and autosaves once a minute. This seems to work fine for me, but I use firefox. Other users with more timesheet entries, and IE7 have problems with IE memory usage increasing and their browser slowing down.

I ran Sieve (checks for memory leaks on a website) and it was pretty obvious it was bad:
[alt text http://rodh.org/images/Programming/sievemain.png](http://rodh.org/images/Programming/sievemain.png)

Thats my site loaded up and left running for a bit, refreshed it at the dip and left it and you can see once a minute it jumps up a little bit. THe area on the timeline before the dip was when i was hitting the save button a bit, so its obvious what is causing it. The DOM nodes and memory both go up.

I'm using a ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock's (mainly to get the clientID's of controls so I can do javascript totals) and also a ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript on page_load to get set the focus to be the same after a partial postback. Maybe they are contributing?

Is there any tools that can help me out further to this?  Sieve reported alot of empty divs being made when the postback occurs? bit I've never used sieve before so maybe this always happens?
[alt text http://rodh.org/images/Programming/sievnodes.png](http://rodh.org/images/Programming/sievnodes.png)

Is there some sort of code analysis I can do, or something that at least lets me see the new DOM nodes created each time...

I'm thinking hte problem might be to do with my code behind hackery to get the client id's, it stores them in an array, and then recreates taht array on each postback, perhaps something is going wrong there? 
I've uploaded my JS file which does that hackery, and also the code behind in case anyone needs more info.
http://rodh.org/images/Programming/javascript.txt
http://rodh.org/images/Programming/codebehind.txt

So I guess my question is: 
- Can anyone think of anything immediately that would be causing this?
- what are some common causes of increased DOM usage on UpdatePanels (using Jquery too btw)
- what tools can I use to debug?

Comment: RodH, I'm curious as to why you disgraced UpdatePanels? I'm currently using them in a personal project of mine, do you know of a better option than UpdatePanels?

Comment: They are generally frowned upon as they send a whole lot of data back as an ajax call, like the whole viewstate I believe: 
http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/ 

They are great for making things ajax easily and I'll keep using them in the right situation, but they send a whole heap of data, and then regenerate all the html inside of it, which is the problem I had. 
I believe the alternative is to use an asp.net web service and an ajax method call, returning only what you need.
I think they are handy and great, but have leaned towards coding the ajax myself

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue.  A page (with many update panels) and a timer that causes a forced update of the UP contents.  Each time that panel is rebuilt, the browser memory usage grows a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you first hand Microsoft knows about the IE problem([KB 2000262](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000262)) with UpdatePanels.  Its a DOM parser issue.  I had a site that ran fine up until a certain page content size and then IE(all versions) had a fit.  FF and other browsers handled the same pages with ease.

Things I did to make my pages faster:

- Use UpdateMode=Conditional wherever possible
- Implement the KB 2000262 fix

[UpdatePanel Async Postsback slow in IE…Part 3](http://cooldotnetstuff.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/updatepanel-async-postsback-slow-in-ie%e2%80%a6part-3/)